# Short way to add item after item in List?

Tags: c#, .net

If there any short way besides foreach loop and new collection creation to add object after specific object in existing List ?

Just an example:

"amy","jerry","tony","amy","jack".
I want to add "simon" after each "amy" in short way

Comment: If you make an edit, please clearly mark which part you have edited so that previous answers do not look out of place.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use Linq to do this.

```
foreach (var item in values
          .Select((o, i) => new { Value = o, Index = i })
          .Where(p => p.Value == "amy")
          .OrderByDescending(p => p.Index))
{
    if (item.Index + 1 == values.Count) values.Add("simon");
    else values.Insert(item.Index + 1, "simon");
}
```

Uses a foreach but you can put it into a extension method to keep the code clear.

#### Extension method

You can easily put this into a extension method.

```
public static void AddAfterEach<T>(this List<T> list, Func<T, Boolean> condition, T objectToAdd) 
{
    foreach (var item in list.Select((o, i) => new { Value = o, Index = i }).Where(p => condition(p.Value)).OrderByDescending(p => p.Index))
    {
        if (item.Index + 1 == list.Count) list.Add(objectToAdd);
        else list.Insert(item.Index + 1, objectToAdd);
    } 
}
```

Now the call:

```
List<String> list = new List<String>() { "amy","jerry","tony","amy","jack" };
list.AddAfterEach(p => p == "amy", "simon");
```

Comment: Won't this fail enumeration as the collection has changed?

Comment: @DarrenYoung Nope, the ordering requires to process all items in the list, so the enumerable won't notice that the list has been changed. The code is tested anyway and works well.

Answer (score 14):

If you know where you want to enter an item, you can do

```
List.Insert(position, item)
```

See [`List.Insert()` on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sey5k5z4.aspx)

Comment: If i use that i should know each position of item i want to add after but when i add an item to list this will resize the list or maybe i've got something wrong.

Comment: You could just simply use a for loop instead of a foreach loop.

Comment: true but won't length grow each addition ?

Answer (score 5):

You have to use the [Insert(int index, T item)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sey5k5z4.aspx) in a List for adding the element into the List at the specified index.  If index is equal to Count, item is added to the end of List.  This method is an O(n) operation, where n is Count.